# Node.js pre-render middleware for link / route preview (whatsapp, facebook, google, etc)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I’m built a dynamic website in node.js / express.js (backend and frontend). The routes render objects which builds HTML with literal templates. I need a solution for all the dynamic links to display preview info with image when we paste a link on WhatsApp, Telegram, Facebook and so on (og meta tag – all configured already).

I researched on stack overflow and found something that may solve my problem, on this link:

[Prerender Angular app on an already existing Node.js server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48460423/prerender-angular-app-on-an-already-existing-node-js-server)

It suggests a dependency called prerender-node. Problem is that I need a subscription plan in order to use it. For this project, may be ok, because I won’t have so many daily hits and there’s a free subscription plan for under 1000 renders a day. But for other bigger projects, it may not be sustainable as my clients would need to pay for a certain quantity of previews on a monthly basis.

Further details:

- I´m using EJS as the templating engine;
- Here is one of the endpoints which I´d like for a preview link to be created when I paste the URL on any of these social tools (WhatsApp, Telegram, Facebook, etc): https://backendnode.fullstackwebdesigner.com/system/
- Some dependencies, include: express (4.17.1), ejs (2.7.1);

So, anyone has any other middleware suggestions that wouldn’t need a subscription plan or any other solution that doesn’t involve using webpack?

Comment: Lots of dynamic rendering can be done with free, open source template systems such as EJS, Jade, Nunjucks, Mustache, Handlebars, etc...  But, we would need to see exactly what HTML you're trying to build and what the input data is for us to offer a more specific suggestion.

Comment: Capturing screen previews can be done using Puppeteer.  If you want something more than just a screen grab from the site, then you'd have to describe what exactly you want.  I suspect the library you're looking at has a subscription because it probably uses a service that they run and thus they have ongoing costs to run that.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I´m using EJS as a templating engine. I´m going to edit my question to give more details and the link to one of the endpoints.